# Nombre asignado por tema shopper al archivo de estilos para implementar shopper-child

Tags: wordpress

Trato de implementar un tema hijo para la plantilla shopper de wordpress pero no puedo hallar el nombre del archivo css asignado para meterlo en functions.php de shopper-child y allí cargar la hoja de estilos padre  e hijo así:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
   $parent_style = 'shopper-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

osea el valor que le debo dar a `$parent_style = 'shopper-style'`

Answer (score 0):

Fallo. No se carga desde functions, lo que tienes que hacer es crear en la raiz de tu theme-child un fichero que se llame style.css y desde alli hacer una llamada al estilo del padre mediante un @import url("rutadelcsspadre.css");